# object has no method mobipick

Tags: jquery, html-framework-7

Trying to implement a custom datepicker with jquery , Framework7 and mobipick.

Using the following files in the Html file:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/framework7.css">
<link href="../css/mobipick.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/xdate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/xdate.i18n.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/mobipick.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/framework7.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
<input id="r_dob" type="text" ></input>
</body>
```

and in the Js file :

```
jQuery(function($){
    alert('Picker');
    var picker = $( "input[type='text']", this );
    //var picker = $( "#r_dob" );
    picker.mobipick({});
    picker.bind( "change", function() {
        var date = $( this ).val();
        // formatted date
        var dateObject = $( this ).mobipick( "option", "date" );
    });
});
```

Getting the error at this `picker.mobipick({}); that object has no method mobipick`.

Kindly help.

Comment: Can you tell me what it means `picker.mobipick({})`

Comment: was using it this way actually thats y var picker = $( selector ).mobipick({
    dateFormat: "MM-dd-yyyy"
});

Comment: Can you double check if mobipick plugin files are being loaded correctly. No 404's.

Comment: is it something like that mobipick works with jquery mobile only cause i am not using jquery mobile in my application . But i want a mobile datepicker.

Comment: @andybeli i am using local files and not thru the cdn

Comment: if mobipick method doesn't exist, it's probably because you are not loading  the required js files needed correctly. Check in the chrome developer tools network tab if JavaScript files are loaded correctly.

Comment: all the files are loaded as checked in the Network Tab ,, no 404 error but still i am getting the error - Uncaught TypeError: picker.mobipick is not a function @andybeli

Comment: Framework7 already has the built-in datepicker component.[link](http://www.idangero.us/framework7/docs/calendar.html#.VbKT7fmqqko)